# Calculate polygon area for each land cover type (using spatraster object)

Tags: r, raster, data-extraction, terra

I'm trying to calculate the area (and ideally percentage) of a 6 bands within a spatraster (land.sub). I made this spatraster by cropping an original land cover raster to polygon data (which represent presence of seagrass). I'm trying to work out how much of the 6 land cover types are present on my spat raster (land.sub) and have tried using exact_extractr and played around with terra's extract function but can't seem to work out how to go about it.
This is my code:

`library(terra)

```
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(exactextractr)
##READ IN RASTER###
rcp19<-rast("7landtypes/SSP1_RCP19/global_SSP1_RCP19_2050.tif")
crs(rcp19, proj = T)

###READ IN POLYGON DATA AND TRANSFORM TO SAME CRS AS RASTER(CEA) BY TYPING >CMU AND COPY PASTING CRS DETAILS IN OUTPUT#### 
cmu <- st_read("units-attributes-wgs84L2.gpkg") %>% 
  st_transform("+proj=cea +lat_ts=30 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") %>% 
  
  ###FILTER FOR JUST AUSTRALIA FROM TERRITORY1 VARIABLE#####
filter(TERRITORY1 == 'Australia')

###FILTER TO JUST SEAGRASS###
sg<-cmu[, names(cmu)%in% c ("seagrass", "unit_ID")] %>% filter(seagrass==1)
plot(sg)

rcp19
######################EXACT EXTRACTR############################################

###CREAT OBJECT CALLED LAND.SUB WHICH COMBINES RCP19 ONLY WITH WHERE SEAGRASS PRESENT###
land.sub <- terra::crop(rcp19, vect(sg), mask = T)
plot(land.sub)

####RENAME NUMERIC VARIABLES TO LANDCOVER TYPES####
levels(land.sub)<-data.frame(id=1:6, cover = c("water", "forest", "grassland", "barren", "cropland", "urban"))
plot(land.sub)
```

I should also mention when attempting calculations with exact_extractr i kept getting error: columns undefined. Image of my map attached.

[landsub raster with land cover raster and seagrass polygons cropped together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c44UW.png)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot follow your example, but if you want to compute the area for different classes you can do that like I show below.

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
r <- round(r/100)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
```

If you want to subset an area using polygons you can do something like

```
r <- crop(r, v[1:2, ], mask=TRUE)
```

You can count the number of cells in each class with `freq`

```
freq(r)
#  layer value count
#1     1     2    47
#2     1     3   219
#3     1     4   314
#4     1     5   475
```

To compute the area of each class:

```
a <- cellSize(r)
zonal(a, r)
zonal(a, r)
#  elevation     area
#1         2 555404.2
#2         3 555412.9
#3         4 554315.4
#4         5 553053.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When i run freq(r), my output is: layer value   count
[1,]     1     0 5530949. not too sure what this means. my r is a spatraster and the polygon data has 322 obs of 3 variables in my global environment. Do i need to change it to a vector first?

Comment: That means that you have 5530949 values that are zero (when rounded with digits=0), see ?freq. You should not (never) make a vector from raster data.

Comment: Just to add, when i run that code with my polygon data as a vector - my output now returns:  layer 1, value 0, count 55

Comment: Ah, okay thanks. I don't believe I have, I just have the r (raster) data and my gpkg which is sg (or v in ur example)